# ggplot bar chart for time series

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm reading the book by Hadley Wickham about ggplot, but I have trouble to plot certain weights over time in a bar chart. Here is sample data:

```
dates <- c("20040101","20050101","20060101")
dates.f <- strptime(dates,format="%Y%m%d")

m <- rbind(c(0.2,0.5,0.15,0.1,0.05),c(0.5,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1),c(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2))
m <- cbind(dates.f,as.data.frame(m))
```

This data.frame has in the first column the dates and each row the corresponding weights. I would like to plot the weights for each year in a bar chart using the "fill" argument.

I'm able to plot the weights as bars using:

```
p <- ggplot(m,aes(dates.f))
p+geom_bar()
```

However, this is not exactly what I want. I would like to see in each bar the contribution of each weight. Moreover, I don't understand why I have the strange format on the x-axis, i.e. why there is "2004-07" and "2005-07" displayed.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for:

`ggplot2` requires data in a long format.

```
require(reshape2)
m_molten <- melt(m, "dates.f")
```

Plotting itself is done by

```
ggplot(m_molten, aes(x=dates.f, y=value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

You can add `position="dodge"` to `geom_bar` if you want then side by side.

**EDIT**

If you want yearly breaks only: convert `m_molten$dates.f` to date.

```
require(scales)
m_molten$dates.f <- as.Date(m_molten$dates.f)

ggplot(m_molten, aes(x=dates.f, y=value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%y"), breaks = date_breaks("year"))
```

P.S.: See http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf for Hadley's philosophy of tidy data.

Comment: maybe one small question: I wanted to change the labels via `scale_x_date(lables=date_format("%y"))`. This is gives an error that it cant find the function date_format. How can I just display 04, 05,06?

Answer (score 3):

To create the plot you need, you have to reshape your data from "wide" to "tall".  There are many ways of doing this, including the `reshape()` function in base R (not recommended), `reshape2` and `tidyr`.

In the `tidyr` package you have two functions to reshape data, `gather()` and `spread()`.

The function `gather()` transforms from wide to tall.  In this case, you have to gather your columns `V1:V5`.

Try this:

```
library("tidyr")

tidy_m <- gather(m, var, value, V1:V5)

ggplot(tidy_m,aes(x = dates.f, y=value, fill=var)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]